# Maven with JavaFX invalid URL or resource not found

Tags: java, maven, javafx

I have a JavaFX application in which I am attempting, among other things, to load Images and draw them as ImageViews. My project is being set up and run with Maven. My code is in src > main > java and my image is in src > main > resources

In ArcadeApp, the following line produces the error: Invalid URL: Invalid URL or resource not found. Here is the code:

```
ImageView breakoutIV = new ImageView(new Image("breakout_image.PNG", 300, 300, true, true));
```

I have tried many different configurations and I can't seem to get it working.

**Edit**

For some reason the resource folder wasn't references in the pom.xml file. Please excuse the question as I was just learning Maven when it was asked.
The solution was to add this in the pom.xml inside the resources tag:

```
<resource>
    <directory>src/main/java</directory>
    <includes>
        <include>**/*.*</include>
    </includes>
</resource>
```

Comment: That actually looks like it should work, given the information you provided. The resource name `breakout_image.` looks strange, though. Is there really no `png` or `jpg` (or other) extension?

Comment: @James_D My bad, changed the source code and edited the answer. Still not working.

Comment: So check the deployment folder (by default `target/classes`) and see if the image is there.